# Let u and v be nonzero vectors in an inner product space V. Prove that $u-projv(u)$ is or orthogonal to v.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I do know that the question is asking to prove $\langle u-\operatorname{proj}_v(u),v \rangle =0$. But I don't know how to prove it.

By the way, an inner product is not a dot product. I know how to prove it, if $\langle u,v \rangle=u\bullet v.$

Comment: Hint: $proj(u) = <u,v> v$ and then just use linearity of the inner product in the first coordinate.

Comment: ..which needs $\langle v,v\rangle=1$.

Comment: Correction: the definition of proj is most likely
$$
\text{proj}_v(u) = \frac{\langle u,v \rangle}{\langle v,v \rangle} v
$$
(which matches Chris' comment when $\langle v,v \rangle = 1$).

Comment: You know how to prove it for a dot-product, so could you post that?  It's easy to take that proof and modify it so that it applies to inner products.